# cURL: variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, curl

Good day, can anyone help me to figure out what is wrong in my code or if I coded it the wrong way.

The curl part is ok my problem is when I started to get the file using foreach loop the result is broken image.

I've try it in array but nothings happen. I'm new with this, maybe I'm missing something here

Here is my code:

```
    <?php 
$url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; //Base Url
$parameters = ['mode' => 'contributors'];  // riders, current_rounds, contributors, season_entries
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['x-weplaymedia-authorisation:XXXXXXXXXXXXX']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch); // Execute

$arr = json_decode($result,true); // Dump result here.

//print_r($arr);
```

If you run `print_r($arr);` it will display array of fields.

But when I try to point certain fields (**[fwcContributors]**) in my foreach loop code im getting a broken images.

Here is the image of array:

[image: here is the image of array]

Here is the result

[image: here is the result]

What I want is to display their profile picture from **[profilePicture]** and username from **[userName]**.

```
$i=0;
foreach ($arr['fwcContributors'] as $val)
{
if($i++ == 5);
echo '<tbody >';
echo '<tr style="transform: skewX(-20deg);">';
echo    '<td>';
echo '<img src='.($val['profilePicture']) .' style="transform:  skewX(20deg);">' . htmlspecialchars($val['userName']);
echo    '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}

    ?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are nested arrays in `fwcContributors`, of which you probably want `ContributorList` to iterate over:

```
foreach ($arr['fwcContributors']['ContributorList'] as $val)
{
    echo '<tbody >';
    echo '<tr style="transform: skewX(-20deg);">';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<img src='.($val['profilePicture']) .' style="transform: skewX(20deg);">' . htmlspecialchars($val['userName']);
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

(Took the `$i` statements out, as they don't seem to do anything.)

Comment: thank you so much. at first i tried this foreach ($arr['fwcContributors']['player']['contributorList'] as $value) i thought this gonna solve it. i was so dumb. thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to have been able to help you. :)